# matplotlib.pyplot continue after calling show

Tags: python, matplotlib

for debugging purposes I would like to have my script show intermediate steps and not just the final plot when working with matplotlib. The problem is that after calling `plt.show()`, the axis is reset and drawing starts anew. Is there a way to call `plt.show()` and continue working with the same axis?

I am working inside PyCharm.

Code concept:

```
import statements

create part of plot

plt.show()

create next part of plot

plt.show() # Should show whatever was in the first plotted window plus what was added in the meantime

create final part of plot

plt.show() # Should show whatever was in the second plotted window plus what was added in the meantime
```

Thanks!

Edit:
System: Windows 10 running Python 3.7.1 and matplotlib 3.3.3

Comment: This gets a little complicated depending on your backend, but show has a “block” parameter.

Comment: Setting block to either true or false did not make a difference in my case unfortunately. I'll add my system settings in the comment

Comment: Maybe you could write a quick workaround by putting each part of the plotting code inside its own function and repeating all the previous function calls after each `plt.show()`?

Comment: This is likely a pycharm backend limitation.

Comment: @Arne: I thought about doing this, but the code structure would make this very complicated since I have a for loop where I want to see each iteration. Redoing everything forces me to write a nested for loop of a possibly expensive function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet to save the plot as it evolves and then compare the different saved figures.

```
#create part of plot
plt.savefig('first_part')
#create rest of plot
plt.savefig('second_part')
```